# Resampling a timeseries data forward average pandas

Tags: pandas, resampling

My df data is like below.

```
    ts                        Values
    2021-01-01 09:00:00+00:00   0.00
    2021-01-01 09:10:00+00:00   0.01
    2021-01-01 09:20:00+00:00   0.03
    2021-01-01 09:30:00+00:00   0.07
    2021-01-01 09:40:00+00:00   0.09
    2021-01-01 09:50:00+00:00   0.14
    2021-01-01 10:00:00+00:00   0.12
    2021-01-01 10:10:00+00:00   0.14
    2021-01-01 10:20:00+00:00   0.18
    2021-01-01 10:30:00+00:00   0.16
    2021-01-01 10:40:00+00:00   0.14
    2021-01-01 10:50:00+00:00   0.21
    2021-01-01 11:00:00+00:00   0.16
```

My code is for resampling is:

```
    df = round(df.resample('1H').mean(), 2).fillna(0)
```

Here fillna is for filling empty cells forward. So not a big deal.
When I run this code, my output is like below:

```
    ts                        Values
    2021-01-01 09:00:00+00:00   0.06
    2021-01-01 10:00:00+00:00   0.16
    2021-01-01 11:00:00+00:00   0.16
    2021-01-01 12:00:00+00:00   0.07
```

What I actually want is that take values and date from 09:00 to 09:50 and write the values corresponding to 10:00. But the default is like 09:00 to 09:50 is calculated as 09:00. I want this at 10:00.

The expected output is:

```
       ts                       Values
    2021-01-01 10:00:00+00:00   0.06
    2021-01-01 11:00:00+00:00   0.16
    2021-01-01 12:00:00+00:00   0.16
```

Comment: Can you provide the expected output for clarity?

Comment: thanks ;) so you need the [second one in my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71308903/16343464)

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
df['Values'].groupby(df.index.ceil('H')).mean()
```

output:

```
ts
2021-01-01 09:00:00+00:00    0.000000
2021-01-01 10:00:00+00:00    0.076667
2021-01-01 11:00:00+00:00    0.165000
Name: Values, dtype: float64
```

Or to consider 09:00 to be 10:00:

```
df['Values'].groupby(df.index.floor('H')+pd.Timedelta('1h')).mean()
```

output:

```
ts
2021-01-01 10:00:00+00:00    0.056667
2021-01-01 11:00:00+00:00    0.158333
2021-01-01 12:00:00+00:00    0.160000
Name: Values, dtype: float64
```

Comment: The second option meets my expectations. Just out of curiosity if there any way doing this with resampling?

Comment: @bazinga you would need to shift the index 1h forward